# .lnk doesn't open, no errors

Tags: windows-explorer, microsoft-access-2007

I have a shortcut (.LNK) on my desktop to a MS Access database out on a network drive.  When I double click that shortcut I get an hour glass for about 10 seconds and then nothing.  No errors, no access opening, nothing happens.

It appears as if there's not even an MSAccess process running in the background.

The file successfully opens from:

1. The Open dialog in Access
2. The commandline "C:\path\to\MSACCESS.EXE C:\path\to\shortcut.lnk"
3. The commandline "C:\path\to\MSACCESS.EXE C:\path\to\whatTheShortcutPointsTo.mdb"

The file silently fails to open from:

1. Double clicking the shortcut.lnk
2. Double clicking the mdb file that shortcut.lnk targets

At first I thought it had to do with how the link handler operated but the fact that it does the same exact thing when I try to open the mdb directly in explorer makes me think it's an issue with explorer.

I've tried restoring, deleting, and recreating the association with the extension.  I've tried running MSACCESS.EXE /regserver.  I've run out of things to throw at it.

In case this is specific to MS Access 2007; I'm trying to use 2007 :)

Comment: Stupid question, but did you delete and recreate the LNK as well? I don't see that step in your troubleshooting.

Comment: I didn't try that, but wouldn't trying the file directly rule that out?

Comment: Does this only happen with this particular file, or any possible files with .mdb extension? And only with files that are on the shared drive, or also local files? And what about files with the .accdb extension? You also say > It appears as if there's not even an MSAccess process running in the background. But can you check that? Open the task manager and see if a service MSACCESS appears.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you dont have the mdb file set to open with MS Access.  Try the following:

Since you didnt say which version of windows you are using...

**XP:** shift right click the actual file and click "open with" find Access in the dialog that comes up and make sure you have "always use this application..." checkbox checked.

**Win7 or Vista:** right clicking on the file and it should give you the "open with" option I think.  Follow the steps for XP and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear that the mdb extension is associated with MS Access.  Thanks for taking the time to answer tho :)  On a side note; if it wasn't associated wouldn't it open the "open with" dialog?

Comment: note if it was associated with something else by mistake or if the registry key class was set wrong.  Basically you could still have it associated but it's not passing in the right parameter.  Sounds like you should do a install repair on Access to be safe.